# ionic2:<ion-scroll>,how can I scroll to the last element with code in .ts file?

Tags: jquery, scroll, ionic2

following code is html segment:

```
<ion-scroll scrollX="true" style="height: 4rem;overflow: scroll; white-space: nowrap;" no-padding *ngIf="treeId" class="bg-style">
        <div *ngFor="let p of progressArray; let i = index;" class="tree-progress">
            <button ion-button clear [color]="getTextColor(i)" class="tree-progress-item">
                {{ p }}
            </button>
            <ion-icon class="tree-progress-arrow" name="ios-arrow-forward-outline" color="arrowColor" *ngIf="checkLast(i)"></ion-icon>
        </div>
</ion-scroll>
```

well,  scroll horizontal, I want to control Scroll scroll to the last position(last element) when array progressArray added automatically. But I can't find any method the api provided.

Then I used a javascript library https://github.com/flesler/jquery.scrollTo in my project.

First I download this library with `npm`

```
npm install jquery.scrollto --save
```

Then I `import 'jquery.scrollto'`

Then I did like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    var mainScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('scroll-content')[0];
    var last = mainScroll.firstElementChild.lastElementChild;
    $('.scroll-zoom-wrapper').scrollTo(last, 200);
}
```

it does't work.Please help me solve this problem, or have examples ready so I can refer to.

Thanks all!

Comment: there is a service that does this $ionicScrollDelegate or refer to these links https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ion-scroll-scrolltobottom/57899  https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-to-make-the-sccollbar-of-content-element-scroll-down-to-the-bottom-automatically/393/2 http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/

Comment: I want to scroll horizontal, ion-content can't do this.thank you for your reply.

Comment: @maverickosama92, thank you very very much.I saw the links you posted in this evening, I found a author post a answer `element.scrollIntoView()`, yeah, this answer do me a great service.I post my answer to below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem like this:

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    var mainScroll = document.getElementsByClassName('tree-progress-item');
    var length = mainScroll.length;
    console.log('mainScroll-->' + mainScroll + " length-->" + length);
    if (length > 0) {
        var last = mainScroll[length - 1];
        last.scrollIntoView(true);
    }
}
```